# isolated singularity and limit finite implies removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Ash & Novinger's Complex Variables. In [Theorem 4.1.5.](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV4.pdf), we are trying to prove the following:

Suppose that $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0$. Then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$ iff $f(z)$ approaches a finite limit at $z\to z_0$.

---

The $(\Longrightarrow)$ direction is clear to me. The $(\Longleftarrow)$ is what is bothering me. The authors say that $f$ can be defined (or redefined) at $z_0$ so that $f$ is analytic on $D(z_0 , r)$. The definition of removable singularity according to the authors is that the negative terms of the Laurent series at $z_0$ do not occur.

Since $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $f$. We can obtain a Laurent series about $z_0$. That is there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ and $r>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n
\end{equation*}
for every $z\in D'(z_0,r)$ the punctured disk of radius $r$ around $z_0$.

The natural way of extending to all of $D(z_0,r)$ is to define $f(z_0)=a_0$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{-k} (z-z_0)^{-(k+1)} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k (z-z_0)^{k-1}
\end{align*}
for each $z \in D'(z_0 , r)$.

---

I could not proceed from here. How can it be possibly redefined? Hints will be appreciated!

---

EDIT: From [Corollary 2.2.13](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/CV/CV2.pdf) which states that if $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$ and analytic on $\Omega \setminus \{ z_0 \}$ then $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$. So, we all need to do is to define $f(z_0)= \lim_{z\to z_0} f(z)$ and this will make $f$ continuous on an open ball containing $z_0$ and since $z_0$ is an isolated singularity, we have that $f$ is analytic on that open ball.

Comment: Then did you solve the problem? Or is it still confusing in some aspects?

Comment: @Riemann I solved it. However, if you like adding an answer, you're most welcome.